# How do I open a text file in TextEdit from Python on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, file, operating-system

```
else:
   tkMessageBox.showinfo('Report Created', 'Your report was sucessfully created')
   file = 'Student Report.txt'
   os.system('TextEdit'+file)
```

I am writing a program that creates a report from data from a database, writes that data to a text file and then is supposed to launch that text file so that it can be printed.

How do I achieve this?

I have attempted to use webbrowser but no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `/usr/bin/open` OSX utility:

```
NAME
     open -- open files and directories

SYNOPSIS
     open [-e] [-t] [-f] [-F] [-W] [-R] [-n] [-g] [-h] [-b bundle_identifier] [-a application] file ... [--args arg1 ...]

DESCRIPTION
     The open command opens a file (or a directory or URL), just as if you had double-clicked the file's icon. If no application name is specified, the default application as deter-
     mined via LaunchServices is used to open the specified files.

     If the file is in the form of a URL, the file will be opened as a URL.

     You can specify one or more file names (or pathnames), which are interpreted relative to the shell or Terminal window's current working directory. For example, the following com-
     mand would open all Word files in the current working directory:

     open *.doc

     Opened applications inherit environment variables just as if you had launched the application directly through its full path.  This behavior was also present in Tiger.
```

You should also use the [`subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) instead of `os.system`, as it is much easier to avoid escaping issues with it:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['open', '-a', 'TextEdit', file])
```

Comment: +1, BTW, it would be better to mention why the code in the question does not work.