# How to open a file for viewing using Python

Tags: python, macos, text

This may be a confusing question. After writing a text file I would like to execute a command in Python which can open the text file created in a text viewing application, such as the default text editor supplied with Mac OSX. I was wondering how this could be done within the script...? I'd like to specify which program to open it in because the extension won't be automatically recognised.

Comment: You probably want to use subprocess http://stackoverflow.com/a/204049/5616110

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21857203/6469907) is another example of using a [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).  Good luck!

Comment: @pat I've tried using the subprocess routine/module, but I get this following error: `subprocess.call(['open', '-a', 'TextEdit', table_ssp_M33_SWIFT.cat]) NameError: name 'table_ssp_M33_SWIFT' is not defined`

Comment: Put the error'd bit in quotes.

Comment: Did that just before you commented, works like a charm!