# Open a text file with python as a form and know when it closes

Tags: python, file

I want to make a python script that opens a text file that the user can update before continuing (for configurations) and then continue the script once the text editor closes. Is there something in python that will allow me to do this?

Comment: are you using a framework? which one?

Comment: It's a platform specific question. Could you be more precise?

Comment: Exemple on Mac OS X: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856970/how-do-i-open-a-text-file-in-textedit-from-python-on-mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on windows using notepad:

```
import os

cf = "config.txt"  # or full path if you like
if not os.path.exists(cf):
   f = open(cf,"w"); f.close() # create to avoid notepad message

os.system("notepad "+cf)  # call waits until user closes the file
# now the file has been edited by the user
```